# Mojave Install Problem - no WiFi hdware installed

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, mojave

Twice I have tried to upgrade to Mojave. After the install the MacBook Pro is very slow and I get the message that no WiFi hardware installed. Anyone have this problem?

Comment: did you check in About this Mac if it shows your hardware there

Comment: It would help us if you could take a screen shot of your Activity Monitor CPU usage, at least top 10